# mdSidebar by pressing esc button is toggle in Angular Material. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

```
     document.onkeydown = function(event) {
         event = event || window.event;
         var isEscape = false;
         if ("key" in event) {
             isEscape = (event.key == "Escape" || event.key == "Esc");
         } else {
             isEscape = (event.keyCode == 27);
         }
         if (isEscape) {
             event.preventDefault();
             console.log(123213123);
         }
     };
```

This code is look on state of button, but it is native JS and how I could make this functionality works? Because I still don't have a solve. What should I wrote in last "if" state to prevent hiding of sidebar?

Thank you all for help!

Comment: function close(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      return sidenavCtrl.close();
    }

Comment: Also I found this func in angular material code: /**
* Auto-close sideNav when the escape key is pressed.
* @param evt
*/
function onKeyDown(ev) {
var isEscape = (ev.keyCode === $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ESCAPE);
return isEscape ? close(ev) : $q.when(true);
}